# Call Unity function from Java

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity :

I create in Unity a simple cube and put some texture over. I rotate the cube... move camera....then export to android studio. When I run everything looks like in Unity.

But I want to move camera or the cube from android studio code ( programming lines ) and I can not find any way to .."findViewById" or similar to be able to find my cube :)

I try to make a C# file ( I just crate one in assets folder ) and put :

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject respawn;
void Start () {

    Debug.Log("aaaaaaaaaaaaa1111111111111111");
    if (respawn == null)
        respawn = GameObject.FindWithTag("mamaie");


    respawn.transform.Rotate(10f, 50f, 10f);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.Rotate(10f, 50f, 10f);
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.Rotate(10f, 50f, 10f);
}
}
```

So... how can I control my cube ( designed in unity and imported in android studio ) from programming lines ?

Comment: Use AndroidJavaProxy --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/41018028/81306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call C# function from Java with `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage`.

This is the what the parameters look like:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName", "MethodName", "parameter to send");
```

In order to have access to this function, you have to include *classes.jar* from the `<UnityInstallDirectory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono\Release\Classes` directory into your Android Studio project then import it with `import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;` in the Android Studio Project.

Your C# code:

```
bool rotate = false;

void startRotating()
{
    rotate = true;
}

void stopRotating()
{
    rotate = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if (rotate)
        transform.Rotate(10f, 50f, 10f);
}
```

---

Let's assume that the script above is attached to GameObject called "Cube".

To start rotation from Java:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Cube", "startRotating", null);
```

To stop rotation from Java:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Cube", "stopRotating", null);
```

Comment: I did as you describe but i;m getting error : at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(unavailable:-1) ; I modify the boolean rotate and set by default true and after i run it did not rotate by default

Comment: how i;m sure that my text.cs file is "linked" to my project ? When i use UnitySendMessage i suppose to send somehow the name of the *.cs file ?

Comment: i replace la 3-rd parameter from "null" to "" and now it does not crash. BUT :  i recive "SendMessage: object Cube does not have receiver for function startRotating!"

Comment: I founded : The model "Cube" did not have any script selected. After i set the file... it works