# How to wait for async operation (any I/O) in Android java plugin side?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

For a unity game I need to use libs in android-plugin that will send websocket requests. I found out that I have no idea how make the c# code wait for the async operation in android plugin!
I provide a proof of concept case (with simple http get request) to ask my quesiton the simple way. Here are my code that **didnt' work:**

```
package com.example.plug2unity1;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Plug1Class {
  static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  static String doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
  }
  public static String GetPlug2Text() throws IOException {
    String res = "";
    try {
        res = doGetRequest("http://www.google.com");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Unity script will have to call the plugin:

```
void Start () {
    TextMesh txtm = GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
    var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.plug2unity1.Plug1Class");
    txtm.text = plugin.CallStatic<string>("GetPlug1Text");
}
```

**Edit:**
The question **is "not"** how to make http call, it is obvious that from c# I can do it, I would like to learn "how c# could wait an async operation result from plugin, being it an http call or an I/O operation, same way we do by "promises" in javascript. 

**Result:**
My TextMesh does not change the text, while if I do a POC without any async in plugin side, it works. How could I get this to work?

Comment: Why are you making the web request from Java? Why not do it from Unity's C# side?

Comment: That's obvious! I wrote above that I simplified my question in this form. I would like to know exactly the answer to above question: if plugin is doing something async, how c# could wait the response please?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was just making sure you are not struggling with making webreq calls in C#.

Comment: Thanks, any idea about this question is very welcome, I'm stucked now and surfing google is giving nothing, perhaps because I don't know what exactly to search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback to do this. Call the Java unction from C#. In the Java function, start new Thread to perform that task. When that task has finished, do a callback from Java to C# to let you know that the task has finished.

C# sample code:

```
void makeRequestOnJava() 
{
    TextMesh txtm = GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
    var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.plug2unity1.Plug1Class");
    txtm.text = plugin.CallStatic<string>("GetPlug1Text");
}

//Will be called from C# when the request is done
void OnRequestFinished()
{

}
```

Then on the Java side when your task has finished, use `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` to call the `OnRequestFinished` function on the C# side.

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName", "OnRequestFinished", null);
```

You can see how to setup and use the `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775916/call-unity-function-from-java/45776104#45776104).