# Can Android Plugins in Unity run listeners such as onSensorChanged()?

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

So far I am able to retrieve simple values from static functions in Unity from my Android Plugin, my goal is to have this Plugin act as a phone sensor listener, and query the sensor values from inside Unity scripts.
Would this be achievable? If so, are there are online resources I could follow as a tutorial? 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. Write the `onSensorChanged` code in java, build it as a plugin then when `onSensorChanged` is called in Java, use `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` to call your C# function on the Unity side.

Something like this:

```
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("TheNameOfYourGameObject", "NameOfCallbackFunction", Arrays.toString(event.values));
}
```

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775916/call-unity-function-from-java/45776104#45776104) describes how to setup `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` in your Java plugin.

---

Note that you don't have to do this. There is a free Unity plugin you can use which already implemented all the sensor API with `onSensorChanged`. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/kshoji/Unity-Android-Sensor-Plugin) and it is very easy to use.

Comment: This is more than what I could have asked for, thank you kind sir!